# Symfony2 and mod_rewrite URLs not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony

I have this pattern configured in my `routing.yml`:

```
/{customer}/{site}/content/{id}.{format}
```

Now I want to omit the `/{customer}/{site}` part and rewrite it with a rewrite rule.
Symfony already has a `.htaccess` with a rewrite rule. I modified it to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php/foo/bar/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I point my Browser to `http://localhost/content/42.html` I get this Exception:

```
No route found for "GET /content/42.html"
```

I fiddled around a bit and found out, why this problem occurs: Symfony uses the `_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to parse the request, but when you use mod_rewrite, the URL in this var is not the expected `/foo/bar/content/42.html` but `content/42.html`.

I could replace the `app_dev.php` with my own one and overwrite the `REQUEST_URI` but I don't want to hack Symfony.

**Edit**:
Removing the `/{customer}/{site}` part from the routing config is no solution because I'm working on a multi customer/multi site application and I want to hide those parts via an URL, so that I can point my browser to `www.my-fancy-site.com` and the apache rewrites this URL to `/foo/bar/content/42.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good that you asked:

Do sth like:

```
app/config/routing.yml:

blog:
  pattern: /{customer}/{site}/content/{id}.{format}
  defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Blog:view ,customer:foo, site:bar }
```

And don't touch the rewrite rules in `.htaccess` or `app_dev.php` at all

EDIT: For your updated question  you will need this, too:

```
app/config/routing.yml:

blog:
  pattern: /
  defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Blog:view, customer:foo, site:bar, id:4 }
```

But this way the url keeps `http://host/`. I would use a welcome controller and then simply redirect from that to the other route... One Redirect should be ok.

To be more precise: You will need two routes and a controller just for redirecting to yours.

Please RTFM here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#route-parameters-controller-arguments

and here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for your tip but this doesn't work for me, I clarified my question. Sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: @prehfeldt I think the solution is spot on, it should work. The actual problem is not with URL rewrite but with the way you have defined routing. I got confused with $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] as well but that's actually not the issue here.
Considering your example of http://localhost/content/42.html
Once the request hits app_dev.php or app.php, then symfony will look for route /content/42.html, so you need to define this route in symfony.